# g++ 4.8.5 : does not give a valid preprocessing token using ##

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I have an error "does not give a valid preprocessing token" when i try to compile my program with G++ 4.8 in Linux . and i do not have error when i compile it in Solaris with CCSuntudio.

below my code :

```
#include <iostream>

#define func(type1,varname1) \
        cout << "ma var est "<<##varname1<<" et le type est "<<#type1; \
        cout <<endl;

using namespace std;

int main() {
  func("int", "area");
}
```

It work perfectly in CCSunStudio but not with G++

```
hello.hxx:2:23: error: pasting "<<" and ""area"" does not give a valid preprocessing token
  cout << "ma var est "<<##varname1<<" et le type est "<<#type1; \
                       ^
hello.cxx:7:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘func’
 func("int","area");
 ^
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit and describes what the error is. So what is your question?

Comment: `<<` and `"area"` are not valid preprocessor tokens, so you can't `##` them together.  I  guess you probably made a typo and meant a `#` single hash there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to use `##` every time you use an argument in a macro.

You only need that when you want to *concatenate* the argument with some other text, to form a single "token". For example, if you had "bo" and "ol" and wanted to make "bool".

In this case, `<<` and `"area"` should be distinct tokens. In fact, `<<"area"` would not be a valid token.

Since your argument is a token in its own right, you literally just write it there in the code:

```
#define func(type1,varname1) \
    cout << "ma var est " << varname1 << " et le type est " << #type1; \
    cout << endl;
```

Tokens are almost words, but they're programming language words rather than English words. You can read more about *tokens* in a book or guide about parsers.

*(You may still need `#type1`, because that does something different: converting the argument into a stringised version of its value. However, since you're already passing a string `"int"`, currently you don't need it there either.)*

---

> It work perfectly in CCSunStudio

Actually this means it *doesn't* work properly in Sun Studio!

> i do not have error when i compile it in Solaris with CCSunStudio.

That appears to be because Sun Studio has a level of compatibility with antique K&R C, [which did things a bit differently](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjakd/index.html).

You can use [the `-xtransition` option](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjapr/index.html) to find other places where your code needs updating to be standard-compliant.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer, i have a question, is there any option to skip this error with g++ compiler ? because this code above is just an example, i have the error in many c++ class on a project in my company, and i prefer to skip this error than modify code.

Comment: @AbdelhakimAitErrami You cannot make GCC accept this wrong code; it simply doesn't understand the code. You will have to fix the code.

Comment: It looks like you can use the `-xtransition` option in your Sun Studio compiler, to identify other places where you are using antique K&R C rather than ISO C (with Sun Studio apparently still accepting some combination of both). Then you can fix _all_ those problems, resulting in a standard, portable codebase. ([ref](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjapr/index.html))

Answer (score 1):

In this case g++ is right. The semantics of `<<##varname1` is that `<<` and the expanded value of `varname1` is pasted into one token, i.e `<<"area"` is treated as a single token by the compiler and since this is not a valid token it reports an error.